# Phonegap do I need to use eclipse/xcode? or what is wrong?

Tags: cordova

I put a small app together yesterday and things went exceptionally well (first time using phonegap, so yes).  Purely html, javascript and css.

I added a listview, and bound it to my viewmodel using mvvm (kendos framework).

I then added two more tab items in my tabstrip, namely my location and camera.
This is where the fun starts (note sarcasm).

My location worked fine in the browser (showing me my x and y position) and my camera said not supported (which is fine).  I then package the app using the phonegap cloud services and it churns out the apk, ipa, etc.

I installed it on my android devices (S4) and the only thing that works is my listview.  No camera, no gps co-ordinates.  I checked the apps permissions and it has the required permissions to do so.

Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Confix.xml

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
```

however I have this (is this the problem)

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

Thanks
Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have mistakes in your `config.xml` [**check it here,**](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) it explained very clearly.
Otherwise you missed `OnDeviceReady` event in your page

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
}
```

> Update:

```
include `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />` // depends on your version
```

Comment: I have the on device ready event, as it works on my desktop web browser

Comment: if u r using phonegap cloud service to build, no need to mention cordova version; just use tag as shown..
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

Comment: I will post code now, it doesnt seem like I have the phonegap.js in the config, let me try that first.

Comment: no need of it in config.xml, u paste that tag in ur html pages.

Comment: build service still complains about `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />` and the geolocation plugin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39475/discussion-between-mvp-and-johan)